# How to update UI, wait some time and update it again using threads in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, ios7

I have an app where I need a blue button with text 'Hello' to glow red and show the word 'Alert'. Then revert back to blue and text 'Hello'. How can I do it?

I know how to use threads for model-based tasks, but not for UI-based tasks, which apparently HAVE to be on the main thread. I am not very good in using blocks though.

Basically the thing I want to do is this (in pseudo-code):

```
- (void) animateUIAndRevertAfterSomeTime
{ 
  // update button title to @"Alert" using setTitle: forState:
  [self.thisButton setTitle: @"Alert" forState:UIControlStateNormal;
  // set buttons' backgroundColor to redColor
  self.thisButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

  // start timer for 10 seconds
  // once time is up
  {
      // update button title to @"Hello" using setTitle: forState:
      [self.thisButton setTitle: @"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal;
      // set button's backgroundColor to blueColor
       self.thisButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  }
}
```

Can anyone do the above in Objective-C without hanging up the app interface for 10 seconds? :P

Comment: You know how to use `NSTimer`, but not how to do something when it fires?

Comment: I meant doing things using threads to UI-based changes

Comment: Start a timer on the main thread and it will fire on the main thread so you can update the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsobject_class/reference/reference.html#jumpTo_43) can do this:

```
- (void) animateUIAndRevertAfterSomeTime
{ 
 // update button title to @"Alert" using setTitle: forState:
  [self.thisButton setTitle: @"Alert" forState:UIControlStateNormal;
  // set buttons' backgroundColor to redColor
  self.thisButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  // start timer for 10 seconds
  // once time is up
  [self performSelector:@selector(updateButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
}


-(void)updateButton  
{
  // update button title to @"Hello" using setTitle: forState:
  [self.thisButton setTitle: @"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  // set button's backgroundColor to blueColor
   self.thisButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

---

Alternatively you can use NSTimer to achieve the same thing:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateButton)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
```

Comment: So this performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: does not block the main thread or anything and the UI remains responsive?

Comment: is this the only thing you want to update? it should be fine..Did you get a chance to test it

Comment: The important point is that the UI update needs to happen on the main thread, but the delay during the timer should not block the main thread. I personally would prefer an NSTimer because you can set it to repeat forever without having the selector re-schedule itself after each invocation.

Comment: Ok, I added an example with NSTimer @RobP

Comment: Two problems with that -- you want a *single* call with repeats:YES outside the actual repeating method, and you want to hold on to the returned value so that you can stop the timer later if you like (and can release it or dealloc it!).

Comment: guess I should have just answered it myself but didn't want to steal the thunder from your perfectly acceptable answer ;)

Comment: You can post one if you want, or edit mine. Community you know `:P`

Comment: Wrong. When using `performSelector:`, the selector will be performed on the same thread. Same with `NSTimer`, as they're added to the runloop of the current thread. So none of your examples will be executed on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call any UI relevant method from a thread. 
You can call mehtods, that perform UI stuff, with `performSelectorOnMainThread` type invokations. 
Regular `performSelector`type methods don't guarantee that it will run on the UI thread.

Comment: true, but that's more of a comment than an actual answer to the question, no?

Comment: `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` _is_ in fact documented to use the current thread.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know, which I did not do. I used it so far only when I did not care on which thread it was executed.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, you don't **HAVE** to be on the mean thread to perform UI stuff...
That being said, it's obviously recommended, as the UI element are not synchronised between threads.

So in order to be safe, you can use the following, using GCD:

```
- ( void )myThreadedMethod
{
    /* Do you heavy work... */

    dispatch_async
    (
        dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        ^( void )
        {
            /* UI related stuff, dispatched on the main thread */
        }
    );
}
```

This way, the content of the block passed to `dispatch_async` will be executed on the main thread.

Note I used `dispatch_async` instead of `dispatch_sync`, because dispatching synchronously something on the main thread while in the main thread will simply dead-lock...
So it adds a little security in the case you call your threaded method accidentally on the main thread.

Otherwise, you can use `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` from `NSObject`:

```
- ( void )myThreadedMethod
{
    /* Do you heavy work... */

    [ self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector( myUIUpdateMethod ) withObject: nil waitUntilDone: NO ];
}
```